# derivative of $\frac{d}{dn}(1+\epsilon/2n)^n.$

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

I need to show that derivative of $\frac{d}{dn}(1+\frac{\epsilon}{2n})^n > 0.$

I use formula $(a^x)' = a^x\ln x.$

For now i have:
$\frac{d}{dn}(1+\frac{\epsilon}{2n})^n = (1+\frac{\epsilon}{2n})^n \ln{(1+\frac{\epsilon}{2n})}(-\frac{\epsilon}{2n^2}),$ where $-\frac{\epsilon}{2n^2}$ is derivative of $(1+\frac{\epsilon}{2n}).$ But this is less than zero. What is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** You may write
$$
(1+\frac{\epsilon}{2n})^n=e^{n \log\left( 1+ \frac{\epsilon}{2n}\right)}
$$ and use
$$
(e^u)'=u'\times e^u
$$ giving here
$$
\left(n \log\left( 1+ \frac{\epsilon}{2n}\right) \right)'\times e^{n \log\left( 1+ \frac{\epsilon}{2n}\right)}
$$ or 
$$
\left(\log\left( 1+ \frac{\epsilon}{2n}\right)- \frac{\epsilon}{2n}\frac{1}{\left(1+ \frac{\epsilon}{2n}\right)} \right)\times(1+\frac{\epsilon}{2n})^n.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note: $a^x = (e^{\ln a})^x = e^{x \ln a}$, so by the Chain Rule $(a^x)' = e^{x \ln a}(\ln a) = a^x \ln a$.

(Thus the formula you quoted has a typo.)

More importantly, though, that formula only applies if the base $a$ is a constant; in your case the base is itself a function of $n$, the variable of differentiation.

If your variable appears in the base only (and the exponent is a constant), then you use the Power Rule.  If your variable appears in the exponent only (and the base is a constant), then you use the formula above.  However, if your variable appears in both the base and the exponent, then you should probably use Logarithmic Differentiation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation